# python ip output error

Tags: python, subprocess, output

From this script i only want to print the ips which have 'bytes from' and save that output in txt format.
after adding the if statement,i'm still getting the full ips. Please help.

```
import subprocess

with open('ips') as f:
    line = f.readlines()
for i in line:
    p1=subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c 1',  i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    output = p1.communicate()[0]
    print(output)

    if 'bytes from' in line:
       print(output)
```

Output:

```
PING 10.11.1.1
(10.11.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.11.0.92 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 10.11.1.1
 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Comment: You have two `print(output)` statements. One conditional and one not conditional. Remove the first one.

Comment: If i remove the first print.. i didn’t see anything on my screen.

Comment: This is an example where correctly formatting your source code will show problems. Correct your displayed code to be indented the same as your problem code.

Comment: I attempted to clean up your formatting errors. I had to guess the indentation of your code. Please review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to avoid `subprocess.Popen()` for anything unless you know for a fact that none of the higher-level wrappers like `subprocess.run()` will do what you want.

The immediate problem with your code (to the extent that the broken indentation can be inferred) is that you are examining all the output lines at once. You need to split the output from `ping` into individual lines and only then examine each line for a match.

Of course, it also doesn't help that you are examining the IP address, not the output from `ping`... Naming your variables to better indicate what they contain are a good way to avoid that sort of error.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

with open('ips') as ips:
    for ip in ips:
        ip = ip.strip()  # remove trailing newline
        ping = run(['ping', '-c', '1', ip],
            stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        for line in ping.stdout.split('\n'):
            if 'bytes from' in line:
                print(line)
```

None of the lines in your example contain "bytes from", though; do you mean "bytes of" perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Buddy, Its working.. :) And yea there is bytes from when the ip is working. and can you dm me please can i ask you some more doubts.. Please.. thanks a lot bro.

Comment: You can chat when you earn 20 rep. There is no facility for private messages.

Comment: Ohh Okay. Buddy one more thing. Its waiting for 1 ip, when its finished its doing the other one. In bash if we add & in end, it became fast. And All the ips are able to ping at one time.

Comment: You can use `subprocess` to run processes in the background. Perhaps then you will need to revert to `Popen()` though. Running multiple processes in parallel and polling for when one of them produces output is challenging. And you are reinventing existing tools anyway - search for `multiping` and `fping`.